# Comparing data in two different database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have two oracle databases who share database objects for example:

**Table: PRICE**

I am looking to come up with a efficient way of comparing the table object between the two databases. I expect them to be identical, but there can be differences as a **new** patch could be applied to one of the environments let's say.

I have been looking at potential solutions and I had a look at using Oracle's `DBMS_COMPARISON` package to compare the two database on the object:

Here is the [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17516/tdpii_diverge.htm#TDPII093)

The issue I am having is that my requirement involves looking at `key`, `values` for each of the objects. For example:

```
Table   Key                          Compare
PRICE   Code,Type,Date,Currency      Price
USER    USER_ID                      FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, DOB
```

My question is...is there a way I can specify the `key` columns and specify the field to compare? Or Do I need to create `temp` tables and then compare the `temp` tables instead of the actual tables?

I'm looking to output the column where the difference is in. Appreciate if you guys can show me an example :)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I've never used it, but according to the documentation, you can specify which index to use (which allows you to indirectly specify the key colymns);  if you do not want to compare all other columns, you could create single-tabls views and compare them instead of the tables.

Comment: Did you actually read the `DBMS_COMPARISON` documentation that you link to? The answer is there.